# NANT copy all files with similar name

Tags: batch-file, copy, nant, xcopy

I am converting an existing batch script into a nant script.

the batch file originally made this call, which appears to copy all files with the same prefix to a directory.

```
xcopy /y /s "paths\name*.exe" Directory\
```

I know how to copy a folder tree in nant, but this is different.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I used this:

```
<copy todir="target\similars" >
    <fileset basedir="source\similars">
        <include name="similar*.txt" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

The wildcard `*` in the `include` element is what lets me specify differences in the filenames.